# Get line by line from a .txt document in java with a custom end of line

Tags: java

I would like to get line by line from a .txt document, but the end of the line should be considered to be: "/". For example:

```
-This is the first line /

- This is the
second line/
```

The method should return me:

-This is the first line /

-This is the second line /

I have tried to solve it using the Scanner class as follows using useDelimiter:

```
FileInputStream text = new FileInputStream (filepath);
alltext = new Scanner (text) .useDelimiter (pattern);
```

, but I have not been able to find a method of the Scanner class that allows me to modify the end of line. It doesn't necessarily have to be with the Scanner class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Scanner` works fine for me, just using `next()` to read each *line*, after setting delimiter with `useDelimiter("/")` - you can also use `StringTokenizer`

Comment: Is changing the `line.separator` system property an option? Then you'd be able to use `Files.lines` or other native utility methods. But this will have an impact on output as well.

Comment: @user15793316 Yes, using next() works for me. The problem was that I was using nextLine(). If you want, answer the question and I will mark it as an answer. Thank you